# is it possible to resolve template T to array reference instead of pointer to an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, c++17, overload-resolution

Disclaimer: This is an **XY problem** kind question.

Is it possible to resolve `template <typename T>` to `(const T (&)[N])` overload instead of `(const T*)`?
For example:

```
template <typename T>
void _print_type(T)
{
    std::cout << "not a c array\n";
}

template <typename T, size_t N>
void _print_type(const T (&)[N])
{
    std::cout << "ref c array\n";
}

template <typename T>
void _print_type(const T *)
{
    std::cout << "pointer to c array\n";
}

template <typename T>
void print_type(T t)
{
    _print_type(t);
}

int main(){
  print_type("oceanic"); // prints "pointer to c array\n"
}
```

**And why `_print_type("oceanic");` results in ambiguous call?** Isn't it logical to prefer an overload with reference to array when there is one?

---

The XY problem (not part of the question):
Concatenation function which takes differen string types

```
const ct_string staticString = "I am static";
concat("string literal", staticString, "another literal"); // yields contigeous ct_string
concat("string literal", staticString, std::string("dynamic string")); // yields std::string
```

- One can figure the lenght of a `const char*` at compile time. One **can not** enforce a check whether `const char *` is a string literal.
- One can not use a variadic list of `ct_string` for arguments like `template <size_t ... N> constexpr auto concat(ct_string<N>...)` since `N` is impossible to deduce even with deduction guides for `ct_string`.

Comment: `print_type` prints a pointer because when you pass an array "by value" into `print_type` it decays to a pointer immediately, all information about it being an array is lost. `print_type(const T &t)` resolves that, and results into your second question about ambiguity. The best answer I have is "because the standard says so".

Comment: Literal strings like `"oceanic"` are really constant arrays of characters. As such they can be used either by the reference to array overload, or by the pointer overload, which makes it ambiguous.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude They are `const char[8]` (for some length 8), aren't they? The same ambiguity happens with `const int[8]`

Comment: @yeputons Yes the same ambiguity should happen for any constant array.

Comment: `void print_type(T t)` -- here `T` is already `const char *`. This ship has sailed.

Comment: Actually, if you take a reference to `const char*` (`_print_type(const T *&)`), there is no ambiguity. I suspect it happens because of "lvalue-to-rvalue conversions" or something.

Comment: @yeputons ok. But is it possible to preserve the information about size `N` when variadic arguments of different types are involved? So that the underlying call would also receive `const T (&)[N]` isntead of `const T*`? One can make a variadic template of `size_t...N`, and it will work with literals, but it will not work with mixed types such as `std::array` or some static string type

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I can have `template <size_t ... N> constexpr auto concat(const char (&)[N] ...)` but it will not accept anything but literals.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Just take and pass variadic arguments by reference, not by value.

Comment: Sounds about right, but what exactly that has to do with the fact that the array already decayed to a `const char *`, in `print_type()`, is unclear to me.

Comment: @yeputons I suspect that passing by reference will somehow prevent optimisation. Hence I decided to pass by value

Comment: `void print_type(T t)` to `void print_type(T&& t)`.  That'll get you closer.

Comment: @Eljay wouldn't it prevent the optimization?

Comment: Arrays are not passed by value.  Also `std::is_array<typename std::remove_reference<T>::type>::value` might be useful.

Comment: This is the most clear and useful comment. I suggest you write an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CWG recently decided that binding a reference-to-array to an array argument should be considered a better implicit conversion than decaying the array to a pointer. [CWG 1789](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#1789)

Until the wording of the standard is updated and compilers start implementing the new behaviour, you have to work around the ambiguity by taking the argument by forwarding reference:

```
template <typename T>
void print_type(T&& t) {
    if constexpr(std::is_pointer_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>) {
        // call pointer implementation
    } else if constexpr(std::is_array_v<std::remove_reference_t<T>>) {
        // call array implementation
    } else {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice. But as I know forwarding references can't be used with value semantics. Hence for variadic templates it is either `Ts...` or `Ts&&...`. So value semantics are not possible when passing string literals :(

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik Are you saying that string literals cannot be passed by value? That's true. But you can manually convert them into `std::array`s, I guess.

Comment: I don't want that, it is far from pretty. See XY section of the question. `cat("The ", "big ", "brown ", "fox")` looks far superior than having each literal converted to `std::array`. That conversion itself is not a one-liner.

Comment: @SergeyKolesnik You can pass string literals to `cat` and have the conversion done inside `cat`'s implementation. And then after that's done, you can pass by value as much as you want.